# How to make a sub form depends on the value selected from the dropdown list

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii

```
labelEx($model,’categoryid’); ?> dropDownList($model,’categoryid’,CHtml::listData($dataReader, ‘categoryid’, ‘categorydescription’),array(‘prompt’=>’SELECT’));?> error($model,’categoryid’); ?>
```

I want to create a sub form depends on the categoryid value.

I have itemcatproperty table, it contain categoryid, label, controltype. If the control value is 0 means its a text box and 1 for dropdown list,2 for checkbox. If I select one categoryid from the dropdown list  I want to include these controls and label names into the form.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

- Include the different form fields in the view file, and use javascript for hiding/showing the proper fields (or field groups) on the dropdown's onChange.
- Use AJAX to load the subform on the dropdown's onChange.

Maybe make your problem a bit more concrete so we can suggest the most appropiate solution?